# How to get a copy of a JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jcomponent

I have a `javax.swing.JButton` which I have created to sign out. How can I get an exact copy(duplicate) of the button to another `JFrame`?

```
private JButton signOut;    

public JButton getBtn(){
    //Any idea?
}
```

`return signOut;` is not an option, because then it will screw the home page when I call `setBounds()` or `setVisible()` of `signOut`.

Do I have to create a new Object of the class with the button to get only this component? Or is there another solution?

Comment: You can't 'return signOut' because you are only copying the reference to the original Button object.  Is there a copy constructor in the definition of JButton?

Comment: *"How to get a copy of a JComponent?"* A copy or an instance? Note that since a `JComponent` can have only a single parent container, 'copy' does not make much sense.

Comment: And why would you need a copy? And what you mean exactly by a **copy**? Why not just create a new `JButton` object?

Comment: @tmarwen because I have done some designing.. setting font, icons, etc... So it would be much easier if I could get a copy of the object without writing the whole code again...

Comment: @AndrewThompson not an Instance. a duplicate of the object.

Comment: You probably don't want a duplicate or a copy.  I like Jeremy's answer: make a method and put the code in that method to create buttons.  It would help if you could show us more code or describe *why* you want a copy; I feel this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where there's probably better solutions than trying to copy a button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract the building of that button into some sort of factory or function. This way, you don't have to constantly manually reconfigure the button nor do you have to worry about copying / cloning (which can get very messy)

```
public JButton createButton(string caption) {
   //Create button here
}
```

Comment: Yeah... that's what i did. but I was wondering whether there's an easier way... Because you can't do this when you are using an IDE like netbeans. it won't let you change the code. However good idea, thanks.

Comment: I think finding some way to copy a JButton _might_ be easier as far as writing code, but it is definitely more complicated and less clean as far as what it is actually doing and what the intention is. Better to just keep it simple sometimes. In netbeans, you can modify the frame code to add a function.

Comment: *"you can't do this when you are using an IDE like netbeans"* It's certainly possible in Netbeans, so until you figure out how, it's probably best to avoid being hobbled by the IDE.

Answer (score -1):

Ok then, you can copy that button and paste in another panel. Go back to the old frame. Copy that button code. Just come back to the next frame. Click on the button action and paste it. ☺